# Best measure to inform how predicted value can differ from real one

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, pandas, metric, score

I have trained a regression model and obtained a pandas series of the predicted values.
I am working on a "calculator" that will be able to return a predicted value after entering an input sample. I would like to inform an end user, how this predicted value can differ (something like range: min | predicted value | max).

The input dataset on which the model was trained has many outliers, hence I suppose that adding / subtracting a constant value like [mean_absolute_value](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_error.html) to / from the predicted value is not the best idea.

What is the best approach to this problem? Which metric should I use? Ideally from some sklearn module.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to compute/output *confidence intervals* for each prediction because, often, you are not given the true data at inference. Basically you decide how much wide your interval should be, the wider the less confident. The intuition is that the true value is contained within the interval with some probability $p$, whereas your prediction is always inside the inteval.

For practical implementation, assuming linear regression, you may want to look at these two answers: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74673133/21113996) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36400419/how-to-calculate-the-99-confidence-interval-for-the-slope-in-a-linear-regressio).

Another way would be to directly use models that can estimate confidence, like [Bayesian](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#bayesian-regression) and [Quantile](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#quantile-regression) regression, or even a [Gaussian Process](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/gaussian_process.html#gaussian-process-regression-gpr).

Comment: Thank you! I will read about that. One question arose: how this approach is better than the percent MAE? I've just found  it on sklearn (link: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error.html)

Comment: @Paulina If you have access to the true value, then you can use this metric but also MSE, RMSE, or even the [$R_2$ coefficient](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html#sklearn.metrics.r2_score).